# Conducting rod moving through magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge

If a conducting rod moves through a magnetic field which way do its electrons move?

In my revision guide it shows the following picture (more or less, but the following is my drawing of it -- I didn't change anything):

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding why the electrons accumulate on the end of the rod shown in the picture. Surely by  Fleming's left hand rule the flow of positive charge will be in the direction of the green arrow here:

[image]

Which means that the electrons flow in the opposite direction to the green arrow, so the "plus" and "minus" signs in the rod are the wrong way round in this diagram. It should be like:

[image]

Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Fleming's left hand rule: index finger - field, middle finger - current.

Comment: @AV23: Thumb -- thrust (force)

Comment: Yes, that too. But I suspect the mistake is in associating quantities to these fingers.

Comment: @AV23: No I did it like you said: field -- index finger, current -- middle finger, force -- thumb. But I think I know what I did wrong now, apparently I was meant to use my right hand instead because the current is being generated by motion, not the other way round. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/181260/flemings-left-hand-rule/181261?noredirect=1#comment382646_181261

Comment: @AV23: Yes I got the hands the wrong way round: Left hand rule is for motors being driven by current (current --> motion), while right hand is for generators creating current by motion (motion --> current)

Comment: Well, the left hand rule is applicable here too, if you use it the right way - the "current" is due to the "Motion", and the force is where the charges are pushed to on the rod. (All following from $\vec{F} = q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$)

Comment: @AV23: But it gave the wrong direction. Sorry, I might be misunderstanding you.

Comment: Index finger along "Field" and middle finger along "Motion" - the thumb gives the direction of positive charge buildup. But this is too trivial a thing to get hung up on. To each their own preferred rule.

Comment: @AV23: Ah I see, swap the fingers and it works. Thanks, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

Let us imagine that the charge carriers in the rod are electrons (negatively charged). An electron moving to the right is equivalent to a (conventional) current to the left. Alternatively, you can use a "left hand rule" for electrons (since the current is to the left when the motion is to the right, you can represent electron motion with the thumb of your left hand, or conventional current with the right hand).

Either way - with your right hand thumb pointing to the left, and your index finger pointing down, your middle finger is pointing towards you: so that is where the force of the magnetic field is pushing the electrons, and that is why the negative charge accumulates on the side of the rod facing you.

Your mistake was in looking at the divided charges and concluding there will be a current along the wire; as long as the rod is moving at a steady rate through a homogeneous magnetic field, there will be no flow along the rod (after the charge has split as shown).

Answer (score 1):

To use rules without knowing what is the reason is boring. See my [paper](https://www.academia.edu/12037987/About_the_internal_cause_of_Lorentz_force_electric_and_magnetic_induction) about vector product for Lorentz force, for generators and for electric drives, in a reduced form for perpendicular vectors only. If one isn't sure that this equations could be derived see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221942/how-to-rewrite-a-vector-cross-product-with-orthogonal-vectors) from mathematicans. See my answer [Why does one call $B$ the magnetic induction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/181145/why-does-one-call-b-the-magnetic-induction/181294#181294) too.

If one not want to make some the calculations but want to find the directions only you can use these vector products for every angle between these vectors expect zero angles. You have to use for all three equations or the right hand or the left hand (for the flow of electrons or for the technical direction of current).

Accepting these three equations one can see how electrons electric charge and electrons magnetic dipole moment and the movement of the electron are related.