# Fleming's left hand rule

Tags: magnetic-fields, charge, conventions

in [Fleming's left hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_left-hand_rule_for_motors) is the direction of current showing the direction of the flow of electrons or the direction of positive charge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Wikipedia article on the left hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_left-hand_rule_for_motors). It says:

> The direction of the electric current is that of conventional current: from positive to negative.

Comment: Thanks, but then how do we explain this? : http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/181246/ (If I'm understanding the wiki quote it's saying that the current in fleming's left hand rule is flow of positive charge?)

Comment: @user45220: Because that's a generator not a motor, i.e. it's using motion to create a current not current to create motion, so you need to use the **right** hand rule.

Comment: Wow my book doesn't have anything on the right hand rule. I'll need a new book after this.

Comment: @user45220: the [Wikipedia article discusses the right hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_left-hand_rule_for_motors#Distinction_between_the_right-hand_and_left-hand_rule)